# Storing messages for node.js chat in redis. How?

Tags: node.js, redis, chat

I implemented chat for one website in node.js + javascript front end.
I decided to use Redis for perstisting conversations so when user refresh page he can get all conversations. Conversations should be stored based on server session.

I wanted to know is there any way to store hash with lists as values in redis?
For example, something like:

```
client.rpush("conversations:"+conversation_id, message);
```

I wanted to store conversations in format of hash with key [sender_id]#[receiver_id]. That way when someone log in I get all conversations where that user is participant by running throught all conversations. This way I need some time to go thorugh all conversations and get only those for user. How this will affect performance ?

Or second way, maybe better way would be to store messages for user in format:

```
rpush(user_id, {sender: sen, receiver: rec, content: con, timestamo: tmstp})
```

This way I can easily recostruct all conversations for user and show them when user is logged in.
Advantage of this approach is that I need less time to get all user conversations (I get it directly from list), but this takes more space, because same message is saved twice, in sender's and receiver's message list.

What you mean, what is better approach?

Comment: Why not use regular database? They are good at querying.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea about this. publish all the messages(with usable format) to a channel in redis and create some subscribers with your preferred language and store these messages to DB as batch inserts.